# How to get panel screen from remote in c#

Tags: c#, desktop

I have created a Remote desktop application. But now I want to create a remote doolder application. But it has a problem. Now I can't solve this problem.
I can't get specified panel bounds. It show a piece of screen size. I want to get the panel content.

Here is the code:

```
namespace client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        private NetworkStream mainStream;
        private int portNumber;

        private Image GrabDesktop()
        {
           // Rectangle bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            Rectangle bounds = panel1.Bounds;

            Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X,bounds.Y,0,0,bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            return screenshot;
        }

        private void SendDesktopImage()
        {

            BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            mainStream = client.GetStream();
            binFormatter.Serialize(mainStream, GrabDesktop());

        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Control.DrawToBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var screenshot = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(screenshot, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));
```